# Google My Business API - accountID Location

Tags: google-my-business-api

GET
[https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{**accountId**}/locations/{locationId}/reviews/{reviewId}](https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/%7B**accountId**%7D/locations/%7BlocationId%7D/reviews/%7BreviewId%7D)

Where is the accountID located in the API documentation?

Answer (score 3):

In order to understand you should study well [https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/overview] and then [https://developers.google.com/my-business/ref_overview]

it seems that you are just interested in working in playground [https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground]
step by step go forward:
from [https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials] copy your clientId and use it as the OAuth Client ID while selecting OAuth flow
=client-side , look at the photo:
[image]

then enter https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground  as the photo below
[image]

then press Authorize Apis, next you need to sign in using the username and the password of the client you are going to do all these stuff for.
after that you can work in playground for an hour. If the time expires, you should follow the aforementioned steps again.
as it is highlighted in the photo below you should enter the values:
the request uri you see in the photo is going to be deprecated soon, the new one is
https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts
or
https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/accounts
[image]

finally, at the right side window you are provided by a json response that you can see accountId

Comment: hi, where can I find the locationID?

Comment: Then you need to read first, locations list: the Request URI: while the method is GET: https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/locations but you should know that this API is going to be deprecated soon, the new api for locations list is called google.mybusiness.businessinformation.v1.Locations and you can read more about it here [https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rpc?hl=en%5D#google.mybusiness.businessinformation.v1.locations]

Comment: @yeln did you solve your problem?

Comment: @ShilaMosammami Could you please share how to get locationId?

Comment: @Newbie_developer first you read all accounts' lists [https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/accountmanagement/rest/v1/accounts/list], then all the locations' lists [https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations/list]. You will have a json response and the value of "name" key contains your location id , something like locations/1365475239725486. the numbers after "locations/" would be the locationId

Comment: @ShilaMosammami Could you please link to docs again or the API? The above links are going to 404 page missing.

Comment: @Newbie_developer Sorry I do not know why it is not working. Anyway,  for account you can search on google: `My Business Account Management API`  
and for the locations  you can search  `My Business Business Information API`

Comment: The links above go to the link with an extra ] added in. I think it was part of the comment that stackoverflow accidentally read as part of the link.

https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations/list
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/accountmanagement/rest/v1/accounts/list

These work for me

Answer (score 1):

I will explain how to find out the account ID.

GET
If you run https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts

you will be required to authenticate with OAuth2.0.
if the authentication passes,
for example something like "name":"accounts/1234555" will appear.
Now, "123455" is your mybusiness's accountID.