# Find LocationId using api for Google My Business API

Tags: google-developers-console, google-my-business-api, google-business, google-business-profile-api

I'm trying to use this API to get all Google business reviews

```
https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/locations/{locationId}/reviews
```

But here I need accountId and locationId. I want to make use of api to get both these values.

I was able to find accountid using the API but can't figure out how to get locationId.

This was suggested by few posts but this is not working.

```
mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts{accountId}/locations
```

Could someone help me get locationId using api?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official doc](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/accountmanagement/rest/v1/accounts/list), you can retrieve the list of accounts by doing the following http request:

```
GET https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts
```

This should give you all the accounts related to your parent account.

Similarly, you can get all the locations from a given account (doc [here](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations/list)) in this way:

```
GET https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=accounts/*}/locations
```

The request you posted is deprecated (see [here](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations/list)) as Google is moving from the **v4.9** version to more granularly services (info [here](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/sunset-dates)).

Answer (score 0):

The API you are using seem to be expired. Have a look at this link [My Business Account Management API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/accountmanagement/rest/v1/accounts/list) for reading all your Accounts and Account IDs

The HTTP request for reading accounts:

```
GET https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts
```

, and this link [My Business Business Information API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest) to have the list of Locations.

The HTTP request for locations:

```
GET https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=accounts/*}/locations
```

In addition, you might be interested in reading the answer provided for  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66108943/google-my-business-api-accountid-location/69854485#69854485)